# Ajuda com relacionamentos avô, pai e neto no laravel

Tags: laravel, relacionamento

Estou aprendendo e gostando de utilizar o laravel, mas estou com algumas duvidas sobre os relacionamentos e como obter o resultado que quero.

tenho as tabelas:

```
TB_FORMULARIO
 - ID_FORMULARIO
 - NO_FORMULARIO

TB_CAMPO
 - ID_CAMPO
 - ID_FORMULARIO_FK
 - NO_CAMPO

TB_PREENCHIMENTO
 - ID_PREENCHIMENTO
 - ID_CAMPO_FK
 - TX_PREENCHIMENTO
```

E nas classes models tenho os seguintes relacionamentos:

```
 class Formulario extends Model{
   ...
   public function campo(){            
     return $this->hasMany('App\Campo', 'ID_FORMULARIO_FK', 'ID_FORMULARIO');
   }
 }

 class Campo extends Model{
   ...
   public function formulario(){            
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Formulario', 'ID_FORMULARIO_FK', 'ID_FORMULARIO');
   }

   public function preenchimento(){            
     return $this->hasMany('App\Preenchimento', 'ID_CAMPO_FK', 'ID_CAMPO');
   }
 }

 class Preenchimento extends Model{
   ...
   public function campo(){            
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Campo', 'ID_CAMPO_FK', 'ID_CAMPO');
   }
 }
```

Com isso no meu controller de formulários eu consigo acessar os dados da tabela campo (que seriam os campos de um formulário) fazendo um find por ID_FORMULARIO conforme abaixo:

```
public function buscarFormularioCampos ($idFormulario){
    $formularioCampos = Formulario::find($idFormulario)->campo;
    ...
    return response()->json($formularioCampos);
}
```

Mas se eu quiser ir um nível a mais e trazer os preenchimentos de um campo partindo de um formulário pelo seu ID eu recebo um erro:

```
public function buscarFormularioCampoPreenchimentos ($idFormulario){
    $formularioCampoPreenchimentos = Formulario::find($idFormulario)->campo->preenchimento;
    ...
    return response()->json($formularioCampoPreenchimentos);
}
```

Eu acredito que pelo mapeamento feito seria possível o laravel entender que a partir da tabela "avô" estou tentando acessar a tabela "neto", há algum erro de mapeamento? Será que devo mapear de alguma forma o relacionamento com o neto na model avô também? Estou pesquisando o assunto mais ainda não encontrei uma solução mais prática sem ter que partir pra escrita de querys.

Comment: Chama a Cristina Rocha, virou Casos de Família :P :D

Comment: Qual.o erro? No caso você precisa acessar o método depois o outro relacionamento.!

Comment: O erro é: Exception
Property [preenchimento] does not exist on this collection instance. Teria como exemplificar este acesso?

Comment: O resultado que quero é semelhante ao da query: `SELECT p.* FROM tb_preenchimento p WHERE p.id_campo_fk IN (select id_campo from tb_campo where id_formulario_fk = {$id_formulario})`. Mas queria fazer isso direto (sem ter que montar a query), só pelo mapeamento dos models que seria algo como o trecho `Formulario::find($idFormulario)->campo->preenchimento;` , mas que não é aceito pelo laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o método `hasManyThrough` que possibilita você ligar Formulário diretamente ao Preenchimento.

Na model Formulário ficará da seguinte forma:

```
 class Formulario extends Model{
   ...
   public function campo(){            
     return $this->hasMany('App\Campo', 'ID_FORMULARIO_FK', 'ID_FORMULARIO');
   }

   public function preenchimento(){            
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Preenchimento','App\Campo', 'ID_FORMULARIO_FK', 'ID_CAMPO_FK', 'ID_FORMULARIO', 'ID_CAMPO');
   }
 }
```

Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through